# How to implement spring OAuth security with Jersey?

Tags: oauth, spring-security, client, jersey

I want to implement spring security on a jersey Restful web service, both on server and client side. 
The goal is to guarantee user authorization and authentication when he wants to access a protected ressource. I tried a solution by implementing the ConsumerDetailsService and UserDetailsService interfaces on server side and used a CoreOAuthConsumerSupport on client side(calling readProtectedResource). 
This works, but the problem is that is doesnot take advantages of the jersey client, for example for passing an array as parameter.

Is there a Jersey client implementation of OAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Jersey has support for OAuth on both the server and the client side. See the following javadoc pages:

[OAuth Server](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-oauth/oauth-server/index.html)
[OAuth Client](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-oauth/oauth-client/index.html)
[OAuth core classes](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-oauth/oauth-signature/index.html)

There is also a twitter client sample application under Jersey samples that uses OAuth: http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/show/trunk/jersey/samples/oauth-client-twitter?rev=5569